# Cannot echo result from a query

Tags: php, sql, class, function, pdo

I have a **class**, where i have a **function** with the following **query**.

```
public function count_weight() {
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT sum( weight ) FROM `fish` WHERE `user_id` = '".$_SESSION['id']."'");

    try {
        $query->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

    return $query->fetchAll();
}
```

I want to echo out this result on my index-page. Right now it looks like this:

$weight = $users->count_weight();

echo $weight;

Which obviously doesn't work, it only prints out "arraykg".

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to iterate over the result using `foreach`. Or since your query looks like it should only return one row and one column, instead of doing `fetchAll` do `fetchColumn`

Comment: Why are you not using a prepared statement with parameter??

Comment: Mike - Thanks! fetchColumn did the trick.

Comment: @CheesePuffs You should really used bound parameters for prepared statement for proper security/SQL injection prevention. You should also look into `stmt::bind_param` and `stmt::bind_result`

Comment: Daryl Gill - Thanks for the tips! I'm learning as i go, care to give an example? :)

Comment: @CheesePuffs This is not the time nor place for it at the moment, read over the manual, if you get stuck google has tons of examples

Answer (score 2):

You can't print an array like that. e.g.

```
$arr = array(1,2,3);
echo $arr;
```

is going output the literal text `Array`, because you're using the array in a string context. If you want to print the CONTENTS of the array, you'll need to do something with it, e.g.

```
echo implode(',', $arr); // prints: 1,2,3
```

or

```
print_r($array); // debug dump out of the array
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for example:

```
$weight = $users->count_weight();
foreach($weight as $w)
{
   echo($w['id']):
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$query->fetchAll();` will return an array. Use `var_dump()` to analyze the array and adjust your variable  declaration accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($weight);
echo "</pre>";
```

Assuming `$weight` actually contains data and is not a resource.

Comment: This is to check the array is correctly populated, and should (mostly) be used as a debugging step, this will not echo out an element from the array, rather the entire thing

Answer (score 0):

$weight is an array of the row that it retrieved. You'll need to echo out that column

```
echo $weight['weight'];
```

This may or may not work because of the query. Try changing the query to this:

```
$query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT sum( weight ) AS weight FROM `fish` WHERE `user_id` = '".$_SESSION['id']."'");
```

Comment: Actually using `fetchAll` produces a zero-indexed array of all rows, so you would actually need to do `$weight[0]['weight']` because it returns ALL rows. If you are using `fetch`, it will only return one row and `fetchColumn` only returns one column of one row.